# Visual Studio 2013 Document Outline tool always empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, visual-studio-2013, editor, document-view

I'm currently editing a large CSS-file in the Visual Studio 2013 editor, and would hugely benefit from a tool that hierarchically listed the content of the files I'm editing. From what I understand, the Document Outline (DO) tool in VS is supposed to achieve this, however, it never actually displays anything; regardless of the document I am editing while the DO panel is visible (CSS, C#, JS, XML etc..), it just tells that:

```
There are no items to show for the selected document.
```

First of all, is the DO the right tool for the job, and if yes, how do I get it to display my pages' content? Am I perhaps missing some dll-files?

For the reference, I am developing an asp.net-MVC application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to install the [Mexedge Stylesheet Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b6dd8050-77fa-4dba-998f-dabdd255d96d) that displays CSS structure in Solution Explorer.